# ONGR ElasticSearchBundle Mapping in Document Class

Tags: elasticsearch, ongr

i installed the ONGR ElasticSearchBundle in my Symfony Project. To search a Index with Company Names and  Descriptions, the index Name is companies. It looks this way:

```
 "mappings": {
        "_doc": {
            "properties": {
                "id": {"type": "long"},
                "entityid": {"type": "long"},
                "entityname": {"type": "keyword"},
                "name": {"type": "text"},
                "street": {"type": "text"},
                "city": {"type": "text"},
                "zip": {"type": "long"},
                "ziptext": {"type": "keyword"},
                "regionisocode": {"type": "keyword"},
                "desc": {"type": "text"},
                "branch": {"type": "text"},
                "branchid": {"type": "long"},
                "foundingyear": {"type": "date"}

            }
        }
    }
```

Then i used the console tool to create a Document.

```
/**
 * Company
 *
 * @ES\Document()
 */
class Company
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ES\Property(type="long", options={"index"="not_analyzed"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ES\Property(type="long", options={"index"="not_analyzed"})
     */
    private $entityid;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ES\Property(type="keyword", options={"index"="not_analyzed"})
     */
    private $entityname;
...
```

This seems to work so far. The connection to the ElasicSearch host is working, but i don't get a search result even if i do a MatchAllQuery() i asume that this is an mapping issue? Mayby someone has a hint?

Sincerely

Answer (score 0):

Don't have any experience with the tooling you're using (next to ES), but have you actually indexed/inserted any documents?

If you have ES running locally, try out: `localhost:9200/companies/_search` to verify if there are any documents and whether the index has actually been created.

Did you follow [these](https://github.com/ongr-io/ElasticsearchBundle#step-4-create-index-and-mappings) steps? Also [here](http://docs.ongr.io/ElasticsearchBundle/crud) you can find some more information about indexing data.

Happy coding! :D

Comment: Hi Byron, 
so far i'm using official PHP client for Elasticsearch, but there is no DSL i decided to install a PHP-ES Lib. I don't made changes on the index and it's working when i use only the ES- PHP Client. And yes i created the index with the console commands of the ONGR bundle an i also read the ONGR Documentation. I'm asumming, that it has something to do with the Mapping?